# Error: Duplicate zip entry [43.jar:org/apache/http/annotation/NotThreadSafe.class]

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, ioexception, android-studio-3.0

**Problem:**

**Error after upgrading to Android Studio 3 : Error:java.io.IOException: Duplicate zip entry [43.jar:org/apache/http/annotation/NotThreadSafe.class]**

Would appreciate some help in figuring out the issue. Seems related to apache library or something, not sure what it is about the annotation. This setup was working fine on Android 2.3, since I updated am getting this error and its been hours trying to fix the issue. I've enabled `multidex` support and all that but seems like this requires a more specific fix. Cheers

just updated to `androidStudio3`. Unfortunately when I run the build I get the following 4 errors:

```
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\MICHAEL\AndroidStudioProjects\Project\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\MICHAEL\AndroidStudioProjects\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\43.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [43.jar:org/apache/http/annotation/NotThreadSafe.class]))

Error:java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\MICHAEL\AndroidStudioProjects\Project\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\MICHAEL\AndroidStudioProjects\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\43.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [43.jar:org/apache/http/annotation/NotThreadSafe.class]))

Error:java.io.IOException: Can't read [C:\Users\MICHAEL\AndroidStudioProjects\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\43.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [43.jar:org/apache/http/annotation/NotThreadSafe.class])

Error:java.io.IOException: Duplicate zip entry [43.jar:org/apache/http/annotation/NotThreadSafe.class]
```

the exception in more detail:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\MICHAEL\AndroidStudioProjects\Project\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\MICHAEL\AndroidStudioProjects\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\43.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [43.jar:org/apache/http/annotation/NotThreadSafe.class]))
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:213)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\MICHAEL\AndroidStudioProjects\Project\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\MICHAEL\AndroidStudioProjects\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\43.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [43.jar:org/apache/http/annotation/NotThreadSafe.class]))
    at proguard.OutputWriter.writeOutput(OutputWriter.java:187)
    at proguard.OutputWriter.execute(OutputWriter.java:79)
    at proguard.ProGuard.writeOutput(ProGuard.java:427)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:175)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.BaseProguardAction.runProguard(BaseProguardAction.java:61)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.MainDexListTransform.shrinkWithProguard(MainDexListTransform.java:232)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.MainDexListTransform.transform(MainDexListTransform.java:184)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:222)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:218)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't read [C:\Users\MICHAEL\AndroidStudioProjects\Project\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\43.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [43.jar:org/apache/http/annotation/NotThreadSafe.class])
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:188)
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:158)
    at proguard.OutputWriter.writeOutput(OutputWriter.java:176)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Duplicate zip entry [43.jar:org/apache/http/annotation/NotThreadSafe.class]
    at proguard.io.JarWriter.getOutputStream(JarWriter.java:138)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:106)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:106)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:92)
    at proguard.io.ClassRewriter.read(ClassRewriter.java:68)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
    at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
    at proguard.io.JarReader.read(JarReader.java:65)
    at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.readFiles(DirectoryPump.java:65)
    at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.pumpDataEntries(DirectoryPump.java:53)
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:184)
    ... 50 more
```

here's my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.michael.project"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-vision:v1-rev357-1.22.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26+'
    compile 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.4'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile files('C:/Users/MICHAEL/AndroidStudioProjects/Project/lib/fluent-hc-4.5.3.jar')
    compile files('C:/Users/MICHAEL/AndroidStudioProjects/Project/lib/jna-4.1.0.jar')
    compile files('C:/Users/MICHAEL/AndroidStudioProjects/Project/lib/jna-platform-4.1.0.jar')
    compile files('C:/Users/MICHAEL/AndroidStudioProjects/Project/lib/jsoup-1.10.3.jar')
    compile files('C:/Users/MICHAEL/AndroidStudioProjects/Project/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar')
    compile files('C:/Users/MICHAEL/AndroidStudioProjects/Project/lib/org-apache-commons-codec.jar')
    compile files('C:/Users/MICHAEL/AndroidStudioProjects/Project/lib/jaunt1.3.5.1.jar')
    compile files('C:/Users/MICHAEL/AndroidStudioProjects/Project/lib/commons-lang3-3.6.jar')
    compile files('C:/Users/MICHAEL/AndroidStudioProjects/Project/lib/unirest-java-1.4.9.jar')
    compile files('C:/Users/MICHAEL/AndroidStudioProjects/Project/lib/urlimageviewhelper-1.0.4.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the problem by removing

```
jackOptions {
    enabled true
}
```

and adding

```
android.compileOptions.sourceCompatibility 1.8
android.compileOptions.targetCompatibility 1.8
```

Also, removed all the apache locally imported jars and replaced with these instead:

```
compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6'
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
```

Cleaned and rebuilt the project and now thankfully works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for this question and answer. This helped me to solve a similair issue: after adding the following dependency: `implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:3.0.1'`, I stared having issue in the multidexing. Adding `android.compileOptions.sourceCompatibility 1.8
android.compileOptions.targetCompatibility 1.8` solved this issue.